# member variable as a reference

Tags: c++, reference, member

What is the advantage of declaring a member variable as a reference?
I saw people doing that, and can't understand why.

Comment: Can you give an example. When you say advantage, what do you think it is an advantage over.

Comment: A good answer posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139386/member-variable-as-a-reference

Answer (score 5):

One useful case is when you don't have access to the constructor of that object, yet don't want to work with indirection through a pointer. For example, if a class `A` does not have a public constructor and your class wants to accept an `A` instance in its constructor, you would want to store a `A&`. This also guarantees that the reference is initialized.

Comment: Using references does not guarantee that it's 100% initialized. For example, `void foo( int& x){...}; ... int* a =0; foo(*a);` However, it clearly states that the function/method expects parameter to be initialized.

Comment: @a1ex07: Dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behavior. Asking the question "is the reference initialized?" is meaningless, at that point, so your conclusion fails. It's your fault for dereferencing a null pointer, not his for (correctly) assuming a reference is valid.

Comment: @GMan: I just wanted to say that references in C++ can behave as bad as pointers. When function parameter is a reference, it doesn't mean that it's impossible to pass null or a reference to already deleted object. `int a = new int(); delete a; foo(*a);`

Comment: @alwz07: Dereferencing an invalid pointer is undefined behavior, you're still in the exact same boat as your last objection: you can't have an invalid reference without invoking undefined behavior. The blame is still yours for being silly with pointers. That is, the moment of failure was not assuming the reference is valid, but in your attempt to acquire a reference.

Answer (score 2):

A member reference is useful when you need to have access to another object, without copying it.

Unlike a pointer, a reference cannot be changed (accidentally) so it always refers to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, types with unusual assignment semantics like `std::auto_ptr<>` and C++ references make it easier to shoot yourself in the foot (or to shoot off the whole leg).

When a reference is used as a member that means that the compiler generated `operator=` does a very surprising thing by assigning to the object referenced instead of reassigning the reference because references can not be reassigned to refer to another object. In other words, having a reference member most of the time makes the class non-assignable.

One can avoid this surprising behaviour by using plain pointers.